# jQuery ui sortable tablerows refresh number position inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

In a html table I have in every row a cell with its own position number. How can I refresh this position number correctly after sorting with jQueryUI?

This is my simple html:

```
<table border="0">
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Position number</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Text</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>        
</table>
```

And this is my js:

```
    var fixHelper = function(e, ui) { ui.children().each(function() { $(this).width($(this).width()); }); return ui; };

    $("table tbody").sortable({ 
        helper: fixHelper
    }).disableSelection();
```

Now I'd like to change order correctly position number values after complete sorting.

How can I make this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do the following after sorting ..

```
$("table tbody").sortable({ 
    update: function(event, ui) {  
        $('table tr').each(function() {
            $(this).children('td:first-child').html($(this).index())
        });
    },
    helper: fixHelper
}).disableSelection();
```

you can try (untested) :
instead of `$('table tr').each` use `$(this).parents('table').find('tr').each`

Explanation.. 
It loops through each of the `tr` tags within table and then changes the content of first `td-child` with the index value of `tr`

Comment: Thank you so much, good answer and good explanation, it works perfectly. 
I accept and vote for your answer, you can do the same for my question if you want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Helped me as well - great response and question

Answer (score 3):

If anybody liked the above answer as I did, here's the Coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  $("ul.sortableEdit").sortable
            stop: (event, ui) ->  
             $('ul.sortableEdit li').each( ->
               $(this).children('input.sortableItemPos').val($(this).index())
             )
```