# Table with two tbody's next to each other in table, thead on top

Tags: html, jquery-ui, html-table

I want to create an HTML table that looks like this:

```
    Left context | Right context | Delete row?
-------------------------------------------
1   [input]        [input]         Y/N
2   [input]        [input]         Y/N
3   [input]        [input]         Y/N
```

This seems simple enough. The thing is that I want to make the rows sortable with jQuery UI. That's easy enough as well (call `.sortable()` on the `tbody`), however I find this very ugly because the number moves with the row. What I want is that only the "real" rows move, without the indices (1, 2, 3 and so on). Those numbers should always be in the same spot, but the rows can move around.

I thought I could simply make a new tbody inside the table, after the thead, which would only contain the numbers, and then call .sortable on the tbody that contains only the rows. However, obviously this doesn't work: the tables don't float next to each other, but are placed above each other.

Any ideas how to deal with this? Test case on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqgxrysd/2):

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Left context</th>
            <th>Right context</th>
            <th class="text-center">Delete row?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="sortable">
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control left-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control right-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>

                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control left-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control right-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>

                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control left-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control right-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>

                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control left-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control right-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>

                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control left-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control right-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>

                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="ui-state-default">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control left-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control right-context" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>

                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ui sortable tablerows refresh number position inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741327/jquery-ui-sortable-tablerows-refresh-number-position-inside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using CSS counters in pseudo-elements displayed as table-cells:

```js
$("tbody").sortable();
$("button").on("click", function () {
  $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
td {
  padding: 8px;
}
thead > tr:before {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
}
tbody {
  counter-reset: row-number;
}
tbody > tr:before {
  counter-increment: row-number;
  content: counter(row-number);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Left context</th>
      <th>Right context</th>
      <th>Delete row?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><button type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```